Horizontal split in WezTerm and keep the current working directory. Possible?
OS: Windows 10 |
Shell: Powershell (7)
So, what I noticed is that whenever I split the window in WezTerm into two panes, the created pane does not keep the current working directory and instead defaults to the home directory. After looking a bit into it, it seems to be caused by Powershell, since it does not automatically communicate the directory.
It also seems that I'm not the only person experiencing this issue and I imagine that there surely must be some solution to this.
My idea was pretty simple. I looked into the WezTerm documentation and attempted to configure it to get the cwd of the pane with the built-in function and then just use it. And I made sure to have a fall-back action in case something goes wrong:
local wezterm = require 'wezterm'
local act = wezterm.action
local config = {}

config.keys = {
  {
    key = '<',
    mods = 'CTRL|ALT',
    action = wezterm.action_callback(function(window, pane)
        local cwd_url = pane:get_current_working_dir()
        if cwd_url then
          window:perform_action(act.SplitHorizontal { cwd = cwd_url } )
        else
          window:perform_action(act.SplitHorizontal { domain = 'CurrentPaneDomain' } )
        end
      end),
  },
}

However, when I try to press the button, absolutely nothing happens, which leads me to believe that the fall-back action isn't called, meaning that it does fetch something, but whatever it gets isn't compatible.
NOTE: action = act.SplitHorizontal { domain = 'CurrentPaneDomain' }, works on its own when testing it, but does not maintain the cwd.
So, I also tried adding the following to my Powershell profile:
function prompt {
  $loc = $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation;

  $out = ""
  if ($loc.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem") {
    $out += "$([char]27)]9;9;`"$($loc.ProviderPath)`"$([char]27)\"
  }
  $out += "PS $loc$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
  return $out
}

Unfortunately, nothing changed. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Note that OSC 9 is Windows-specific; WezTerm may use a different one, such as OSC 7; also, perhaps the embedded " chars. aren't expected.

There is no need for the additional command. The default behavior of WezTerm is to use the current working directory when doing a split. The current working directory is inferred through the OSC 7 value.
Your prompt function is not setting the OSC 7 value correctly. This is the correct OSC 7 prompt according to the docs:
function prompt {
  $p = $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation
  $osc7 = ""
  if ($p.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem") {
    $ansi_escape = [char]27
    $provider_path = $p.ProviderPath -Replace "\\", "/"
    $osc7 = "$ansi_escape]7;file://${env:COMPUTERNAME}/${provider_path}${ansi_escape}\"
  }
  "${osc7}PS $p$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
}


Unfortunately, this does not seem to resolve the issue for me. Whenever I do a split, it still defaults to the home directory instead of the cwd. Nonetheless, thank you for the answer.

FWIW, I use Oh My Posh for my powershell config. That has an option to add an OSC7 prompt: https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configuration/general#general-settings
This works for me with WezTerm.
